# Passing array values from a function back into a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct

I am currently working on a program that requires a function to figure out array values and then stores those values in `arr1[]`, which has an unknown size and is calculated within the function.  It then passes back the entire array along with the size of the array back to the main function.  Using a struct, I returned the size, but I cannot return the array for some reason.  Can someone please direct me in the right direction with what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my struct:

```
struct Arr
{
    int size_1;
    int arr_1[];
};
```

And here is part of my function that returns the array, where `arr1[]` is the array in which I need to return:

```
Arr smallElement(int arr[], int size)
{
    Arr tempArr;

    for (int count = 0; count < newSize; count++)
    {
        tempArr.arr_1[count] = arr1[count];
    }

    return tempArr;
}
```

This is what I use in my main function to call the function to print the array, but it just prints 3 random numbers every time:

```
Arr a;
a = smallElement(array, n);
cout << "The array is: ";
for (int count = 0; count < a.size_1; count++)
{
    cout << a.arr_1[count] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Please show your code as [mcve].

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: Just don't do this... This code is error prone, confusing, and in it's current state exhibits UB, afaict anyway. (tl;dr; use a vector)

Comment: Flexible array members or VLAs are not valid C++.

Comment: `count < newSize;` where does newSize come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a `struct`, `int arr_1[]` does not define an actual array. It is actually just a placeholder called a flexible array member. In C, this is used by allocating memory for the fully defined part of the `struct` plus additional space for the array—you have to manually add space when using `malloc` or other memory allocation. In standard C++, you should not use this. (It is not part of standard C++. It is an extension adopted by some compilers from C, where it is standard.)

When you declared `tempArr`, it created just the fully defined portion of the `struct`. When you assigned values to `tempArr.arr_1[count]`, there was no allocated array there, so the behavior is undefined. When you return `tempArr`, a copy of the struct is returned, but, again, only a copy of the defined portion.

If the caller knows the size the array will be, you may want to have them pass the array to the function, perhaps by allocating it with `new` or by using `std::vector` and passing the vector by reference. If the size is not known by the caller, then you may want to have the function allocate the array and return a pointer to it (in which case the caller is responsible for deleting it later), or you may want to pass an empty (or otherwise available for re-use) `std::vector` to the function, preferably by reference. Inside the function, it can add more elements to the vector, and the `std::vector` will manage memory allocation for you.

Comment: _"In C++, you may want to avoid this."_ You should say they **do** want to avoid this, because it's not valid C++ code.

Comment: @underscore_d: Done.